# Test CSS property value for (x) to see if specific media query is active for conditional loading of JS, etc...

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, media-queries

Wondering what issues people may see with doing this.  Here's what's going on that seems to work in a simple POC:

Some media query for all your appropriate styles:

```
@media screen and (max-device-width : 640px) {
  body:after {
    display: none;
    content: 'mobile';
  }
  etc ...
}
```

Then test:

```
var isMobile = window.getComputedStyle(document.body, ':after').content === 'mobile' ? true : false;
```

and then from there obviously:

```
if ( isMobile ) doMobileAndLoadStuff();
```

To me this seems cleaner than a bunch of JS to detect screen size or user agent string whatever.  I know IE8 does not support getComputedStyle but that can be solved easily.  Does anyone think this is good or bad?  Are there gotchas I don't see?  Is there a cleaner simpler solution?

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) is for.

---

### What is Modernizr?

> Modernizr is a small JavaScript library that *detects* the availability
>   of native implementations for next-generation web technologies, i.e.
>   features that stem from the HTML5 and CSS3 specifications. Many of
>   these features are already implemented in at least one major browser
>   (most of them in two or more), and what Modernizr does is, very
>   simply, tell you whether the current browser has this feature natively
>   implemented or not.
>
> Unlike with the traditional—but highly unreliable—method of doing “UA
>   sniffing,” which is detecting a browser by its (user-configurable)
>   `navigator.userAgent` property, Modernizr does actual feature detection
>   to reliably discern what the various browsers can and cannot do. After
>   all, the same rendering engine may not necessarily support the same
>   things, and some users change their userAgent string to get around
>   poorly developed websites that don’t let them through otherwise.
>
> Modernizr aims to bring an end to the UA sniffing practice. Using
>   feature detection is a *more reliable* mechanic to establish what you
>   can and cannot do in the current browser, and Modernizr makes it
>   convenient for you in a variety of ways:
>
> - It tests for over 40 next-generation features, all in a matter of milliseconds
> - It creates a JavaScript object (named `Modernizr`) that contains the results of these tests as boolean properties
> - It adds classes to the `html` element that explain precisely what features are and are not natively supported
> - It provides a script loader so you can pull in [polyfills](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-browser-Polyfills) to backfill functionality in old browsers
>
> With this knowledge that Modernizr gives you, you can take advantage
>   of these new features in the browsers that can render or utilize them,
>   and still have easy *and reliable* means of controlling the situation
>   for the browsers that cannot.

### Why use Modernizr?

> Taking advantage of cool new web technologies is
>   great fun, until you have to support browsers that lag behind.
>   Modernizr makes it easy for you to write conditional JavaScript *and*
>   CSS to handle each situation, whether a browser supports a feature or
>   not. It’s perfect for doing progressive enhancement easily.

### How it works

> For a lot of the tests, Modernizr does its “magic” by creating an
>   element, setting a specific style instruction on that element and then
>   immediately retrieving it. Browsers that understand the instruction
>   will return something sensible; browsers that don’t understand it will
>   return nothing or “undefined”.
>
> Many tests in the documentation come with a small code sample to
>   illustrate how you could use that specific test in your web
>   development workflow. Actual use cases come in many more varieties,
>   though. The possible uses of Modernizr are limited only by your
>   imagination.
>
> If you’re really interested in the details of how Modernizr works,
>   look at the [source code](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/) of modernizr.js and the various feature
>   detects, and [dig into the project on GitHub](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues).

### Supported browsers

> We support IE6+, Firefox 3.5+, Opera 9.6+, Safari 2+, Chrome. On
>   mobile, we support iOS's mobile Safari, Android's WebKit browser,
>   Opera Mobile, Firefox Mobile and whilst we’re still doing more testing
>   we believe we support Blackberry 6+.

Check out the [full list of features](http://modernizr.com/docs/#features-css) that Modernizr detects, or learn more about [conditional resource loading with Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/docs/#load).

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of Modernizr and should have said I'm looking to avoid an additional library, even if minimal.  Just curious is my approach should work.

Comment: @Matt - I understand what you are trying to do, but you _are_ using JS and in that way sort of reinventing the wheel.  Also, you can totally customize Modernizr to only include the features you want.  It's _very_ helpful.

Comment: Again I appreciate the idea of Modenrizer but don't think I'm reinventing anything.  Looking to avoid that as a dependency.  Just looking to see what issues this specific piece functionality may have, maybe none.